# How do I convert a 'undefined' or 'zero' value to string?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I retrieve cell value from google sheet with google app script then it returns 'undefined' when the value in that cell is 'zero'. I need it to be remain zero when I send the values to a email.[Image Result of the cell value where value is zero in google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVE92.jpg)

```
function sendEmails() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template");

  var i,j; var k=4;
     for(i=2; i<=2; i++){ 
       var infoData = [];
       for(j=2; j<=5; j++){

         var cellValues = targetSheet.getRange(i, j).getValue();
         infoData.push(cellValues);
       }

       var emailSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emails");
       var currentEmail = app.getActiveSheet().activate().getRange(i, 1).getValue(); 
       var subject = app.getActiveSheet().activate().getRange(i, 2).getValue();
       var block = app.getActiveSheet().activate().getRange(i, 3).getValue();

       //var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
       //Logger.log("Remaining email quota: " + emailQuotaRemaining);

       var body = "<h3>Dear Sir/Ma'am,</h3>" + 
          "<h3>Daily MGNREGA progress Report on different parameters.</h3>" +

          "<table border = '1'>" +
            "<tr><td>BLOCK: </td><td>" + block + "</td><tr>" + 
          "</table>" +

          "<table border = '1'>" +

            "<tr font-style = 'bold'><td>#S.NO</td> <td align = 'center'> PARAMETERS </td><td align = 'center'> VALUES </td></tr>" +
            "<tr><td align = 'center'>1.</td> <td align = 'left'> Percentage of NRM Expenditure for the financial year 2019-20 (So far) </td><td align = 'right'>" + infoData[0] + "</td></tr>" +
            "<tr><td align = 'center'>2.</td> <td align = 'left'> Percentage of Timely MGNREGA wage payment (T+8 days) FY 2019-20 </td><td align = 'right'>" + infoData[1] + "</td></tr>" +
            "<tr><td align = 'center'>3.</td> <td align = 'left'> Work completion rate FY 2017-18 and Earlier in percentage</td><td align = 'right'>" + infoData[2] + "</td></tr>" +
            "<tr><td align = 'center'>4.</td> <td align = 'left'> No. of Rejected transactions pending Reconcilation of FY 2018-19 </td><td align = 'right'>" + infoData[3] + "</td></tr>" +
            "<tr><td align = 'center'>5.</td> <td align = 'left'> Pending Geotagging Stage- 3 of Phase-II (Completed Works) </td><td align = 'right'>" + infoData[4] + "</td></tr>" +
            "<tr><td align = 'center'>6.</td> <td align = 'left'> FTOs Pending for First signatory FY 2019-20 </td><td align = 'right'>" + infoData[5] + "</td></tr>" +
            "<tr><td align = 'center'>7.</td> <td align = 'left'> FTOs Pending for Second signatory FY 2019-20 </td><td align = 'right'>" + infoData[6] + "</td></tr>" +
            "<tr><td align = 'center'>8.</td> <td align = 'left'> No. of Rejected transactions pending Reconcilation FY 2019-20 </td><td align = 'right'>" + infoData[7] + "</td></tr>" +

            "</td></tr>" +

          "</table>" + 
          "<h4>NOTE: This Alert message is valid for Today only. Thanks</h4>" +
          "<h3>Regards,</h3>" +
          "<h3>DRDA Barpeta</h3>";

       var options = {
         htmlBody : body
       }

       MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subject, "", options);
     }
}
```

Comment: You're using value indices that were never added to `infoData`. (Look at the `for` loop control block: `j = 2; j <= 5;`)

Comment: **Yes u r right  @tehhowch, I found the mistake, Thanks for rectifying my mistake.**

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value to `cellValue` by adding a `|| 0` so that the `cellValue` gets set as `0` if `targetSheet.getRange(i, j).getValue()` returns `undefined`

Try this

```
var cellValues = targetSheet.getRange(i, j).getValue() || 0;
```

Comment: ... or `0`, or `""`, or `false`, or `null`

Answer (score 0):

It'd be really helpful if we could tell what the raw data of `infoData` was (I'm not all too familiar with Google App Scripts), but I'll do my best. Now, this isn't code golf, but we can detect and replace all `undefined` values with `0` with a `for` loop.

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < infoData.length; i++) {
    if (infoData[i] == undefined) {
        infoData[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `i` will never be undefined. Also, `i = undefined` is just assigning `i` with undefined and not comparing

Comment: Sorry, accidentaly put `i = undefined` instead of `infoData[i] == undefined`, changing now :)